# salt-stack: how to get package version in state file and/or jinja template

Tags: salt-stack

Having installed the latest version of package where it expects config files to do be in a path including the version number (e.g. `postgresql-server`), how can I get the installed version number in a variable to be used inside my `state.sls` file so the salt master can:

- manage the config files in the correct path
- use this for paths inside some jinja templated config files

If I can just get the value as a variable in the sls.

I know from the cli I can use the command:

```
salt minion-id pkg.version packagename
```

to return something like:

```
saltmaster:
   9.4+165+deb8u2
```

Update: I can get the correct version use e.g.:

```
{% set pg_version = salt['pkg.version']('postgresql') %}
```

but only if its on the next run.  Is there a way to force a dependency on this?

Update: According to the issue https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/38072 it cannot be done yet unless you use orchestrate.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've managed to figure out is to use the `available_version` part of `pkg` if you are going to install the package anyway so you can do something like this (based on Debian version numbering from default package repo):

```
{% set pg_raw_available_version = salt['pkg.available_version']('postgresql') %}
{% set pg_available_version = pg_raw_available_version.split('+') %}
{% set pg_version = pg_available_version[0] %}
```

then use `{{ pg_version }}` in the state sls or jinja template as that will resolve to `9.4` on Jessie and `9.6` on stretch (currently).